# XPath expression to check if one element matches

Tags: html, xpath, xslt

I'm trying to find an XPath expression that will display an html table header if any one (or more) elements match a users query in an HTML form. However I only want to display the table header once. If no match is found a 'no match found' message will display.

Extract of the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="library.xsl" type="text/xsl" ?>
<Library>
<Book>
<Published>1992</Published>
<Author>Charlotte Bronte</Author>
<Publisher>Wordsworth Classics</Publisher>
<Description>Jayne Eyre ranks as one of the greatest and most perenially popular works of English fiction</Description>
<OnLoan>no</OnLoan>
</Book>
<Book>
<Published>2012</Published>
<Author>Jane Austen</Author>
<Publisher>Penguin Classics</Publisher>
<Description>When Elizabeth Bennet first meets eligible bachelor Fitzwilliam Darcy...</Description>
<OnLoan>no</OnLoan>
</Book>
<Book>
<Published>2012</Published>
<Author>Charles Dickens</Author>
<Publisher>Penguin Classics</Publisher>
<Description>Great Expectations, Dickens's funny, frightening and tender portrayal of the orphan Pip's journey of self-discovery...</Description>
<OnLoan>yes</OnLoan>
</Book>
```

Current XSLT I have tried:

```
<xsl:template match="/Book">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="Book/Published[contains(.,$published)] and Book/Author[contains(.,$author)] and Book/Publisher[contains(.,$publisher)] 
        and Book/Description[contains(.,$description)] and Book/OnLoan[contains(.,$loan)] "> 
            <table>
                <th>Date Published</th>
                <th>Author</th>
                <th>Publisher</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>On Loan</th>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </table>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <p>No matches found</p>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

However this XPath expression doesn't work because it displays the table header if there is a match on, for example, Author and Publisher but within different Book elements. I only want the header to display if an exact Book match is found.

I could use a for-each on each Book but I only want the table header or error message to be displayed once and this will display multiple headers or error messages for each matching Book.

Is there a way to check that each element being checked is a sibling of other elements within the when condition of the XPath expression?

Thanks.

Comment: The XSLT you show is not the XSLT you're using, the XPaths and the match expression make are not aligned to your sample XML. This will never match anything by definition, and it's not useful to fix something that you are not using. Please double-check your XSLT sample.

Comment: Also, please detail what all the variables (`$published` etc.) contain.

Comment: ...apart from that, your XPath uses `and`, but your requirements read *"if any one (or more) elements match a users query"* - that's a contradiction, too.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [**predicate**](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#predicates) - for example:

```
<xsl:when test="Book[contains(Published, $published) and contains(Author, $author) and contains(Publisher, $publisher)]">
```

Or (for an exact match):

```
<xsl:when test="Book[Published = $published and Author = $author and Publisher = $publisher]">
```